# how to substitute underscore of a string in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, rails-admin

I use rails_admin

One of my partial is like this :

```
%b= questionnaire.title

- CSV.parse(questionnaire.content, :headers => true, :col_sep => ",") do |row|    
  - row.to_hash.each do |key, value| 
    = succeed value do
      %b= key  + " : "
```

but key is sometimes like this "I_dont_want_underscore"

I tried this :

```
 %b= questionnaire.title

  - CSV.parse(questionnaire.content, :headers => true, :col_sep => ",") do |row|    
    - row.to_hash.each do |key, value| 
      = succeed value do
        %b= key.gsub!-'_',' ')  + " : "
```

but then I've got this error showing : Can't convert frozen string (or something like this)
Then I tried to duplicate

```
%b= questionnaire.title     
- CSV.parse(questionnaire.content, :headers => true, :col_sep => ",") do |row|    
  - row.to_hash.each do |key, value| 
    = succeed value do
      %b= key.dup.gsub!-'_',' ')  + " : "
```

But then server does not respond anymore...how come ?
finally
I tried to put a def in my application_helper.rb

```
def sub_underscore
 self.dup.gsub!-'_',' ')
end
```

and

```
%b= questionnaire.title
  - CSV.parse(questionnaire.content, :headers => true, :col_sep => ",") do |row|    
    - row.to_hash.each do |key, value| 
      = succeed value do
        %b= key.sub_underscore  + " : "
```

But I get this error : "no method sub_underscore for this string"

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `gsub!` you are modifying the string in place. That's not what you need here. Try using `gsub` instead.